# Is rate of heat loss constant or does it vary?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, temperature

Suppose a body cools from 70°C to 60°C and then again cools from 60°C to 50°C. If surrounding temperature is 30°C then the rate of heat loss from  70° to 60°C would be different to that from 60° to 50°C.

Since the temperature difference between the surrounding and the body is less we can write rate of cooling :-
$$-\frac{\mathrm dT}{\mathrm dt} =k(T-T_0),$$
where $T_0$ is the surrounding temperature which remains constant and $T$ is the temperature of the body at any instant $t$.

Since $T$ does not remain constant ($-\mathrm dT/\mathrm dt$) varies, my question is that if the temperature difference between the body and surrounding and not negligible, then we apply Stefan's law to calculate the initial rate of heat loss. In the Stefan's law, we have to take the difference between body's absolute temperature and surrounding temperature, so if the body is continuously losing heat do we have to always take the starting Temperature of the body at which it was kept or we have change that temperature continuously?

For example, if the initial temperature of the body is $T_1$ and after some time it cools and temperature becomes $T_2$, so the initial heat loss will be $Aeρ(T_1-T')$; then will the rate of heat loss changes when the temperature of the body becomes $T_2$ and rate changes to :- $[Aeρ(T_2-T')]$

Comment: Show us your work so far. Can you state what the equation for conduction is?  Start with that.

Comment: What is the rate of heat loss when the body has cooled to 30 C?

Comment: @EricLippert question updated

Comment: Note that we have an [equation editor built into the site](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/notation) which helps for readability of your post. I've edited some of it for you, but you may want to check it as I suspect the $e$ are exponential functions and the $\rho T$ terms the arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *rate* varies, because cooling is an exponential function. Newton's law of cooling.